# Creating a new NSManagedObject as a binding for a newly presented view creates an infinite loop of NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to set up a modal view in SwiftUI that can be used both to create new objects (assignments, in this context) and edit existing ones. To edit an assignment, I simply pass that assignment to the view as an observed object. I thought it would be simple to also use this view to create new assignments by creating a new assignment in the context while I'm calling the view, like so:

`AssignmentEditorView(assignment: Assignment(context: self.context))`

The view loads just fine but is super laggy and slow. It's been infinitely creating new assignment objects in the context until I close the modal presentation. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could fix it?

I want to have the view create a new assignment as it appears and have that new assignment act as the `@ObservedObject var assignment: Assignment` property of the view.

Edit: Here is the code in context. The sheet is presented on top of the master view when the user taps an "add" button.

```
Button(action: {
    self.newAssignmentViewIsPresented = true
}) {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
         .font(.title)
}
    .sheet(isPresented: $newAssignmentViewIsPresented) {
        AssignmentEditorView(assignment: Assignment(context: self.context))
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.context)
    })
```

Comment: Can you show more context - Where is that line of code?  In a button action handler?

Comment: @Paulw11 I edited the post!

Comment: The cause is described in Lou's answer; You can't create the new entity in the sheet body since that is evaluated many times.  Another approach would be to create an `@State` binding in your view and assign the new `Assignment` to it in the button `action` closure. Then in the sheet presentation call `AssignmentEditorView(assignment: self.currentAssignment)` or whatever

Comment: @Paulw11 Your solution worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that this line

```
AssignmentEditorView(assignment: Assignment(context: self.context))
```

Is a view in a `body` var definition.  The constructions of the views needs to be side-effect free because it can be called a lot.  You should not insert a record into a database every time `body` is called.

Not sure what to suggest, but for example:

```
 AssignmentEditorView(assignmentCreator: { Assignment(context: self.context) })
```

Would let you construct the view without a side-effect.  Then you could call the closure in the editor view when you need the assignment.

Comment: This solved it! I wasn't thinking about how the views can be called more than once, so I used this and implemented Paulw11's answer as well. Thanks!